# What's wrong? Python RSA decryption/

Tags: python, encryption, rsa

> decrypt_message1+=decrypt_message[i]
>
> TypeError: can't concat bytes to int.

`decrypt_message1` and `decrypt_message[i]` are both bytes

```
if int(length)>=1:
    for i in range(int(length)+1):
        decrypt_message1=""
        if i<int(length)+1:
            decrypt_message1=decrypt_message1.encode()
            for i in range(50):
                decrypt_message1+=decrypt_message[i]
            try:
                decrypt = rsa.decrypt(decrypt_message1, privkey)
            except Exception as E:
                print(E)
            decrypt=decrypt.decode()
            text1.insert(END,decrypt)
        else:
            decrypt_message1=decrypt_message1.encode()
            for i in range(len(message)-int(length)*20):
                decrypt_message1+=decrypt_message[i]
            try:
                decrypt = rsa.decrypt(decrypt_message1, privkey)
            except Exception as E:
                print(E)
            decrypt=decrypt.decode()
            text1.insert(END,decrypt)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`decrypt_message[i]` is **not** a `bytes` object. It's an `int`:

```
>>> b"hello"[0]
104
```

Change:

```
decrypt_message1=decrypt_message1.encode()
for i in range(50):
    decrypt_message1+=decrypt_message[i]
```

to:

```
decrypt_message1=decrypt_message1.encode()
decrypt_message1 += decrypt_message[:50]
```

---

Simple subscripts with an index in `bytes` return the integer value stored at that position.
Slicing returns a `bytes` object. See the difference between:

```
>>> b"hello"[0]
104
```

and:

```
>>> b"hello"[:1]
b'h'
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it may be the `+=` operator causing issues because it invokes `__iadd__` instead of `__add__`.

Try `decrypt_message1 = decrypt_message1 + decrypt_message[i]`